# Save image from clipped rectangle in FabricJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fabricjs

I'm using ***clipTo*** function to clip an background image inside a rectangle. Before using clipTo function,i was able to save image successfully from canvas with proper height and width.

But after introducing *clipTo* function, I'm able to save image, but the  background image appeared in final(saved) image looks weird. The color of canvas also appeared in final image.

Following is the image of my canvas.

[image: Canvas]

See my final image,it has 1200 X 1200 dimension. (Here I compressed to reduce the file size).[image: Final image]

This is the script i'm using to add the image to canvas.

```
canvasImage(){
   const base_image = new Image();
   base_image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
   base_image.src = 'assets/images/wallpaper.jpg';

   fabric.Image.fromURL(base_image.src, (myImg) => {
    this.backgroundimage = myImg.set({left: 100, top: 80, id: 'wallpaper'});

    const FakeCanvas = new fabric.Rect({
       originX: 'left',
       originY: 'top',
       left: 100,
       top: 0,
       width: 600,
       height: 600,
       fill: '#fff',
       objectCaching: false,
       selectable: false
    });
  const retina = this.FabriCanvas.getRetinaScaling();

  myImg.clipTo = function (ctx) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.setTransform(retina, 0, 0, retina, 0, 0);
    FakeCanvas.render(ctx);
    ctx.restore();
  };
  myImg.scaleToHeight(800);
  myImg.scaleToWidth(900);
  this.FabriCanvas.add(this.backgroundimage).setActiveObject(this.backgroundimage);
  const hiddenImg = document.createElement('img');
  hiddenImg.src = this.FabriCanvas.getActiveObject().toDataURL();
  hiddenImg.id = 'target';
  hiddenImg.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(hiddenImg);
});
 }
```

This is the code to save the image. I use multiplier:2 to get 1200 X 1200 dimension.

```
saveImage() {
   const image = this.FabriCanvas.toDataURL({
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      width: 600,
      height: 600,
      format: 'png',
      multiplier: 2
  });

 // api call
 this.imageService.upload(image).subscribe((res)=> {
  if(res.data.status === 200){ 
    console.log('image uploaded successfully')
  }else{
    console.log('Image upload failed')
  }
}
```

**What i'm trying to achieve ?**

Final image must consist only the background image and it should have dimension of 1200 X 1200.